# Appending variables to Lists/Call list from another function

Tags: python, list, function, call, extend

So I fixed the issues previous that were based on not having the list defined properly. Is it possible to organize the items in the list? Or is it always going to display the way it was added? If there is a way to update the list after being created and added to, how?

This is the main class file:

```
 def storing():  

    the_item = Ch10b_retailItemClass.RetailItem("","","")

    for count in range(3):  

        desc = input('What item would you like to inventory?\n')
        unit = input('How many of them are in stock?\n')
        price = input('What\'s the price for this item?\n') 

        the_item.set__desc(desc)
        the_item.set__unit(unit)
        the_item.set__price(price)

    # I want to print the list as a whole.
    print(the_item.list_function())
```

And this is my class being imported:

```
class RetailItem:
    global inv
    inv = []
# init function, getting us started and initializing variables?
    def __init__(self, desc, unit, price):
        self.__desc = desc
        self.__unit = unit
        self.__price = price

    # functions that create temp place holders
    def set__desc(self, desc):
        self.__desc = desc
        inv.append(desc)

    def set__unit(self, unit):
        self.__unit = unit
        inv.append(unit)

    def set__price(self, price):
        self.__price = price
        inv.append(price)

    def list_function(self):
        return inv
```

Comment: Please limit posts to one specific question. Please give some concrete input and the erroneous output as well as the desired output that showcases "I cant seem to get the list to save all of the variables, it seems to overwrite when I try to append".

Comment: Now a I am looking back over it, I may have answered one part of it myself. Would the set__desc, etc etc functions run more than once? They would have to run each time the main class is trying to pass the data into it? If that is the case then how do I get around the issue of needing to create the lists for them to use, but then that list is set back to [ ] the next time it is run, isn't it? How do I avoid that?...

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to ask me for?
I'm confused as to what you mean by this:

"Please give some concrete input and the erroneous output as well as the desired output that showcases "I cant seem to get the list to save all of the variables, it seems to overwrite when I try to append"."

Comment: "Not quite sure what you are trying to ask me for?" <- I am asking for a [MCVE]. Currently your question lacks the info needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I narrowed it to a more specific question, removed unnecessary code, gave everything you need to help me out and also verified that it fails by showing the results given to me when I run it.

Does that help you understand my question better to assist? Or do you still need me to do something else to make it better for you?

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. I don't have time to delve into it right now but I gave it an upvote so that others might see it.

Comment: The scope of list `dec_li` is limited to `set__desc()` function only. You can either declare it globally or add this list to the `list_function()` function.

Comment: If I added it to the list function wouldn't it just be creating a new list for that function under the same name? Or does it just pick up where left off? How did I make it global? I can't seem to get it to work when I tried that..

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to figure out how to make the list global. I was using wrong syntax for it. Got the global list to work.     *Is there a way to organize the lists a bit better? Or can you only put data in and call it in the order it was entered? *

Comment: I found another way to do this and completely changed it from this, seems to work much smoother with less code.